# Java servlet not dispatching to another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 servlets, "HomeController" and "SearchController". On the home.jsp I have a form that has a search box and when submitted actions to "Search"

```
 <form action="Search" method="post" name="searchForm">
```

So the first thing the SearchController does is:

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (!validator.isValidAlphaOnly(request.getParameter("breed"))) {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Breed search term invalid. Enter only letters");
        RequestDispatcher requestVar =  request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home");
        requestVar.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Except is doesn't go to /Home even though I have mappings as follows:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.HomeController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SearchController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.SearchController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DogController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.DogController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.LogoutController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UpdateController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.UpdateController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controllers.AddController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Logout</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UpdateController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Update</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DogController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Dog/View/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/Dog/Edit/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/Dog/Add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: does your if condition execute? It executes only if the search term is not a pure-alphabet one.

Comment: Why don't you just remotely debug your application as it's running on your application server, and check what's happening in the post method (i.e. is it really executing the code block that should do a dispatcher.forward when you think it should do that... etc) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getNamedDispatcher:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher requestVar = context.getNamedDispatcher("HomeController");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one your servlet mapping config doesn't quite look right: you have this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
```

Notice the 2 `servlet-mapping` lines?

I expect you just have an error in your web.xml file: your code looks fine.

Comment: I however wonder if that didn't give a XML parsing error on startup. @Sara: it still doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if it is going into the condition.
2. Check if the response is getting committed before forward. It yes, then the forward will fail.
3. Worst case, it could be an issue with your app server.
4. Try using ServletContext.getNamedDispatcher("HomeController"); as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem, your code is actually ok, the web.xml is the one that has the problem:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You have there multiple url-patterns in a servlet mapping.
Try this instead

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It may resolve your issue, web containers are sometimes very picky with these details.

Source: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd

The xsd specifies for the servlet-mapping type:

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="servlet-name"
           type="j2ee:servlet-nameType"/>
  <xsd:element name="url-pattern"
           type="j2ee:url-patternType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

There is no multiple url-patterns there.