# Send request from servlet to servlet

Tags: servlets

Here the scenario, the request from the source servlet send an object request to destination servlet. It seems stuck in sending to destination

```
request.setAttribute("products", products);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/shop");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I did try dispatcher.include even not working at all. When I use response.sendRedirect(), the request sending well. But by this case i have to setSession and I just want to send a normal request so any idea about that ? Thanks

Comment: Which method do you check ? If its original Post then check in doPost for forwarded servlet.

Comment: doPost(), but the request stop in source servlet, the page not forward to destination even

Comment: Try `request.getRequestDispatcher("shop");`

Comment: Please refer....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206273/java-servlet-not-dispatching-to-another-servlet

Answer (score 0):

If you need to forward request from one servlet to another servlet, you just give the servlet alias name (what you configure in the web.xml file) as input for the request.dispatcher(alias name of the servlet) no need to give the "/"

```
like,

request.setAttribute("products", products);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("shop");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```