# Java Servlet dispatcher to another Java file

Tags: java, servlets

**Java**

```
public class Forward extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        req.setAttribute("option", "forward");

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/GotoHere");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);

    }
}
```

**XML**

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GotoHere</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>examples.GotoHere</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GotoHere</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GotoHere</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And I received this error message on the web page: `HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class examples.GotoHere`

I looked this question, [Java servlet not dispatching to another servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206273/) , which is really similar to mine, so I changed

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/GotoHere");
```

to

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getNamedDispatcher("GotoHere");
```

but it's still not working. any ideas?

Comment: Please post `examples.GotoHere`.

Comment: the class name is  examples.GotoHere?

Comment: No, this is "public class Forward extends HttpServlet", the reason why I didn't post GotoHere.java is because the compiler shows errors in this one. and I had try this code by using Tomcat and it works fine, but when I copy it into my Eclipse it doesn't work anymore. I think my XML is correct since both .java file (forward.java & GotoHere.java) are in package "examples".

Comment: Can you post your folder structure on the post? I doubt that your class file is in somewhere that cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 ServletContext context = getServletContext();  
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/GotoHere");
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    req.setAttribute("option", "forward");
    res.sendRedirect("GoToHere");
```